# Interacting With Folders Outside The Root/Web Directory With Dreamweaver (CS5)

Tags: unix, dreamweaver, directory

Using FileZilla, I can access folders that are outside my web directory. How can I do the same with Dreamweaver so that I can edit the files and automatically save/upload all through Dreamweaver? I currently can only access the web directory.

I know how to include them with PHP, but I would like Dreamweaver to find/access them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to set the Site Definition (both local and remote) paths to look one level higher than you currently have it.  So if the local path is

*My Documents/Web Sites/This Site*

you would change it to

*My Documents/Web Sites/*

and if the remote is:

*/user/home/domain.com/*

change to

*/user/home/*

The problem you are going to run into is that Dreamweaver doesn't work well when set like this.  It assumes the Remote path is the public web root and will create all sorts of files and folders there automatically and DW expects those to be in the public root.  Also, things like setting paths to includes and images automatically will start to not work as all paths will start outside of the public web root.

Best to leave it as it is and use an external FTP program to handle the files outside of the web site.

Answer (score 0):

We've bumped up against this situation previously where the desire was to have the PHP include files be moved outside the public HTML directory. JCL1178's answer is absolutely conceptually correct.

The actual implementation was to duplicate the site (under "Manage Sites") and essentially create a separate site for the "includes" directory that would go one level up. So the "Root Directory" setting was normal (in our case "public_html/" in the main site and we removed "public_html/" from the Root Directory setting in the "includes" site, effectively causing the path to go one level up.

Definitely not an ideal situation/workflow, to say the least, as you'll end up with two site definitions for one site (which can cause other issues); but Dreamweaver is what it is. We were working on a project offsite that did not allow for anything other than Dreamweaver to be used, so this is what we came up with to comply.

As an added note: we were only able to implement this solution because the webhosting plan allowed us to get to the root. If you're on a webhosting plan that is strictly limited to the public directory, the whole thing will be DOA.